# Difference between two measures filtered with MDX SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm having an issue concerning a calculated member that calculates the difference between two calculated members. that's how my measures looks like in SSAS Browser :

```
Phase    Measure 1       Measure 2
 P1         50              30
 P2         123             49
 P3         14              69
```

I created a calculated member as `Calculated Member 1 -Calculated Member 2` But when I using a filter with two different Phases I get a blank values.
For instance `From P1 : 50 - From P2 49` I get a blank value.
Phase is a dimension attribute.
I'm using Power BI and I user a filter over Phase for each Measure.

MDX Calculations so far :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Measure 1]
AS ([Indicateur].[LEVEL5].&[R522],[Measures].[Montant]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0,00;-# ##0,00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Fact DAF1';


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Measure 2]
AS ([Indicateur].[LEVEL5].&[R500],[Measures].[Montant]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0,00;-# ##0,00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Fact DAF1';
```

Difference : `[Measures].[Measure 1] - [Measures].[Measure 2]`

How to solve this ?

Comment: Can you post all the MDX calculations involved?

Comment: Post Edited....

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact MDX? Measure 1 and 2 are identical

Comment: Sorry, corrected

Comment: what dimension does Phase come from? Do you filter to two phases in the calculation or in Power BI?

Comment: It comes from a dimension called [Indicateur]. I use two filters in Power BI, each filter concerns a measure.

Comment: what filter do you put on each measure? And can you screenshot the Attribute Relationships tab from the Indicateur dimension and post it. That may be related.

Comment: I put Phase filter. I don't think the problem is related to Indicateur dimension.

Comment: I'm not saying the attribute relationships are wrong but it might explain why you are getting null

Comment: Is [Measures].[Montant] native measure or calculation? It may appear an issue as well.

Comment: it's a native measure

Comment: what's [Indicateur].[LEVEL5].&[R522]?

Comment: have you run SQL Profiler against your SSAS cube to see what command PowerBi sends during that action?

Comment: perhaps phases p1,p2,p3 are categorized as disjoint attributes of [Indicateur].[level 5] hierarchy and because youre trying to difference of different tuples ::: 
i.e **From P1 : 50 - From P2 49**

Comment: So how to solve this ?

Comment: @Anton no i didn't. [Indicateur].[LEVEL5].&[R522] is an Hierarchy attribute.